# Long time operations in MVC and WCF service

Tags: multithreading, wcf, model-view-controller, architecture

I have got a MVC application, that uses WCF service as a connection layer to database. Some operations on WCF are time-consuming. So, what is the best solution for this problem? Should I use async controllers in my MVC application and Task.Factory.StartNew in WCF? Or should I use simple controllers and AJAX in MVC and Task.Factory.StartNew in WCF? Or it is better to use Task.Factory.StartNew in MVC? Or maybe it is better to use simple threads in WCF?

EDITED: 
For example my service generates reports - it takes a long of time. I want user to be able to start generating report and not to wait until it finished - for example show 'generating'. Then he can start generating another one, and etc. After generation of a report is finished - return it to a user.

Please, give the best practices in such type solutions or show me the right direction, thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Best practice depends on all sorts of things - whether you need high-scalability, low latency, fast user feedback etc.

Comment: @Tim Rogers, I've edited my question to make it more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of requirement can be designed in multiple ways as Tim Rogers pointed out in his comment. Judging by your use case focused around reports i would probably do it in the following way:

1. WCF method to initiate generating a report (would initiate a worker thread and return back a process/report id of some sort)
2. WCF method for checking the status of the operation (based on the operation/report id)
3. Regular controller which would call the method from point 1 and allow querying for the status of ongoing jobs for a particular user
4. View presenting a list of historical and ongoing jobs with their statuses (i would probably implement an AJAX request for refreshing the status to get a nice user experience)

Of course this is only a rough description. Whereas points 3 and 4 are easy and straightforward points 1 and 2 may be implemented in a number of ways. You can approach this with implementing your own threading strategy with task persiatance (in memory or db based), you can try using WCF Workflow Service etc. Hope this helps.